# My drop-down menu isn't functioning correctly

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a drop down menu in my website, and when you go to select and option, the list is white, however when you hover over each option, the text appears. I have included an image bellow that shows my issue.

HTML:

```html
<select id="select-a0a8" name="package" class="u-border-2 u-border-none u-input u-input-rectangle">
  <option value="Bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="Gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="Enterprise">Enterprise</option>
  <option value="Undecided">Undecided</option>
</select>
```

If you need any more of the code please just say.

Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant CSS to make it a [mcve]

Comment: Absolutely nowhere near enough information to pinpoint the error here

Comment: This is why the browser comes with [**inspector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) . Right-click your dropdown element and inspect where the colors of the options list are coming from and what are they.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not with your HTML code, The problem is with your CSS, possibly your default option text color is white against the white background, due to which it's not showing any text but when you hover on any option,then CSS is changing styles to grey background with black text, hence you see the text properly,

one thing you can do is to give style property to each option

```
style= "color: black !important";
```

watch the dropdown is working fine without applying any class to it, [codepen](https://codepen.io/Aqib_2000/pen/RwKmpYX)